# in app purchase in application A with application B product

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

think a app A have a product like coin for in app purchase and published in ios or android store.
can the app B use this product in our products?
you think that the application A share a library with custom key for use another application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sort of, not directly, but on iOS, you could use *App Groups* capability with  `-[NSUserDefaults initWithSuiteName:]` to share some values handled by your apps. These need to be operated by the same iTunes organisation and have the *App Groups* entitlement filled and use this group as a suite name as loaded by the method mentioned above.

Let's say – after a purchase you'd set a value within the shared defaults which can be loaded by the other app once it gets focus. But it's all up to you to manage all the stuff. App Store products and purchases cannot be shared between multiple applications so you need to handle the stuff yourselves.